# How to make this custom table rows in MS Excel

Tags: excel, rows

I have a table with custom rows.

Structure of the row:
I have four columns in one row.
2nd and 3rd columns contains arbitrary(say n) cells(default rows in excel).
First and last column must be a single row(n rows merged).

My excel sheet must contain this kind of rows only.

How to design this kind of table in MS Excel(with macros).
I must be able to access these individual cells programmatically.

Comment: What have you done to achieve your goal? Please read [ask] as a starter.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge any number of rows and/or columns in the 'Format Cells' dialog.